# grouping labels and exporting data from Python back to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, grouping, pyodbc, fuzzywuzzy

I am trying to clean a column using fuzzywuzzy using the following code:

```
import pyodbc 
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

# Getting sql list
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;'
                      'Database=AdventureWorks2014;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT top 100 Publisher FROM dbo.Publishers where publisher like '%Ebate%'")

Product_list = cursor.fetchall()

# Groups of names with Levenshtein distance > 77

Groups = list() 
for name in Product_list:
    for grp in Groups:
        if all(fuzz.ratio(name, wd) > 78 for wd in grp):
            grp.append(name)
            break
    else:
        Groups.append([name, ])

print('output Groups:', Groups)
```

outputs:

```
output Groups: [[('Ebates.com', ), ('Ebates', ), ('Ebates Inc', ), ('Ebates.com', ), ('Ebates', ), ('Ebates', ), ('Ebates', ), ('Ebates', ), ('Ebates.ca', ), ('Ebates.com', ), ('Ebates', )], [('ExtraRebates', ), ('Mr. Rebates', ), ('RebatesMe', ), ('ExtraRebates', ), ('Mr. Rebates', ), ('RebatesMe', )] ...
```

Being new to Python, I am stuck finding a way to:

1. Name each group in a separate column.
2. Export the results (grouping, publisher) to a new table on SQL.

Any help is much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

For this, you could just use the pandas library (Just do "pip install pandas" on your terminal / Command Prompt).

You can create a table with one column per each of those results and push this table to your sql database:

```
import pandas as pd
tableresult = pd.DataFrame(Groups).T
tableresult.to_sql('table', engine, index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

in your "to_sql" command:

1. index=False: avoids having an index column pushed in your sql
   table
2. if_exists='replace': one of the way to push a table in sql

For more information, you can check [there](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).

I hope it helps,

BR.